# I am trying to print out the Address a1 of an object person p1 I created. The Person constructor takes in the Address object as well

Tags: java

```
public class Person {
enum Sex{Male, Female}

private String initials;
private String lastname;
private String firstname;
private Sex sex;
private int yearOfBirth;
private double netWorth;
private Address homeaddress;
Sex male = Sex.Male;
Sex female = Sex.Female;

public Person(){}

public Person(String firstname, String lastname, int yearOfBirth, Sex sex, double netWorth, Address homeaddress)
{
    this.netWorth = netWorth;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.sex = sex;
    this.homeaddress = homeaddress;
    this.male = Sex.Male;
    this.female = Sex.Female;
}
public void updateNetworth(double x)
{
    this.netWorth = netWorth + x;
}

public String toString(){
    return("\nName: " + this.firstname + this.lastname + "\n" +
           "Address: " + this.homeaddress + "\nNet Worth: " + this.netWorth);
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Address a1 = new Address (258, "Masachu","New York","USA");
    Person p1 = new Person("John","Brown",1998,Sex.Male,1000.00,a1);
    System.out.println(p1.toString());
    p1.updateNetworth(1000.00);
    System.out.println(p1.toString());
}
```

}

```
public class Address {
private int streetNumber;
private String streetName;
private String city;
private String country;

public Address (int streetNumber, String streetName, String city, String country)
{
    this.streetNumber = streetNumber;
    this.streetName = streetName;
    this.city = city;
    this.country = country;
}
```

}

Whenever I run this my Address field is being printed out as Address@3feba861. I am unclear as to why this is so. So my Person constructor takes in the Address object, but it seems that I cannot print out the person object with the address in this way. How do I go about fixing this.

Comment: you need to override the `ToString()` method of `Address`, otherwise java print object address instead. If you're using the IDE, check for generating code function, here is the Intellij doc https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-code.html

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Override
     public String toString() {
         return "Address{" +
                 "streetNumber=" + streetNumber +
                 ", streetName='" + streetName + '\'' +
                 ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                 ", country='" + country + '\'' +
                 '}';
     }
```